# Linking class instances within other class instances

Tags: python

I'm trying to build out a class where instances within that class may (or may not) be related and at different "weights". The only trivial example I could think of is in a lot of games when there are gems and you can combine lesser gems into better quality ones but where you can also find them independently as a drop.

Also, excuse my butchering of Python, I'm very new and I don't know how to approach this.

```py
class Gem:
    def __initi__(self, name, buyCost, sellCost, ingredients):
        self.name = name
        self.buyCost = buyCost
        self.sellCost = sellCost
        self.ingredients = ingredients

gems = [
    Gem("Chipped Topaz", 2, 1, null),
    Gem("Topaz", 20, 10, 3x[Chipped Topaz]),
    Gem("Greater Topaz", 200, 100, 5x[Topaz]),
    Gem("Prism", 5000, 500, 1x[Greater Topaz] and 1x[Greater Emerald] and 1x [Greater Amethyst])
]
```

So the chipped topaz is a "base" gem, nothing combines to make a chipped topaz, it just is. You can then combine 3 chipped topaz to give a topaz, 5 topaz to give a greater topaz and finally you can combine 3 different greater gems to give a prism.

What I want to achieve is a relationship between all the relevant instances of the Gem class so that I could, for example, easily cascade down the line and work out that for a greater topaz I need 15 chipped topaz. But if I were to change only the topaz instance of Gem to require 4 chipped that that same calculation would say I needed 20 chipped topaz.

To summarize:

1. I want to reference other instances of a class within an instance of the same class
2. The reference can be none, one, or many instances
3. These relationships are weighted (and the weights can change)

I've no idea if I'm going about it the right way. The code above is certainly incorrect and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: and what is the problem? You can use one instance as argument in other instance like in your exaple. But you have to use variables instead of names or you have to keep instances in dictionary and then you can use dict's keys to get instance.

Comment: I'm still getting my head around python as I've just started and I don't kmow how to do some of the really simple things and I don't know if I'm close to getting it right or not. I just don't know how to do what I've asked =(

Answer (score 0):

I see two methods

---

(1) use variables and create first gem

```
gem_chiped_tobaz = Gem("Chipped Topaz",...)
```

and now you can use variable `gem_chiped_tobaz` in next gem

```
gem_topaz = Gem("Topaz", ... [gem_chiped_tobaz])
```

to have direct access to first instance of first gem.

This way you may create three instances of the same class and use them

```
gem_1 = Gem("Chipped Topaz",...) 
gem_2 = Gem("Chipped Topaz",...) 
gem_2 = Gem("Chipped Topaz",...) 
gem_topaz = Gem("Topaz", ... [gem_1, gem_2, gem_3])
```

---

(2) keep in dictionary and then you can use strings

```
gems = {
   "Chipped Topaz": Gem("Chipped Topaz", 2, 1, None),
   "Topaz": Gem("Topaz", 20, 10, ["Chipped Topaz", "Chipped Topaz", "Chipped Topaz"]),
}
```

and then second gem ("Topaz") can use string `"Chipped Topaz"` to get access to `gem["Chipped Topaz"]`

This method seems more usefull but I don't know if it resolves all your needs because it uses three strings `"Chipped Topaz"` which gives access to the same instance, not three different instances.

Comment: Thank you, I know what I want to do in my head but you've given me a good place. It's simple stuff but I could not get the syntax correct. Appreciate your help and I'll report back how I go